# Android official bluetooth chat sample cannot connect

Tags: android

Has anybody meet such a problem? when using the  bluetooth chat sample  , it
says could not connected! i have tested the sample with two android2.1 mobile phone!
anyone who meet such a problem can share the solution?
the code just go to the  socket.accept then it block,could not go !

Answer (score 0):

Do U add permissions to AndroidManifest.xml ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion！but it still cannot work！ maybe the system in my devices throws an exception！ because the system is made in china！ haha  not the official 2.1！ others have solution?

Comment: other apps work with bluetooth correctly, only that don't work?